# Поиск индекса минимального элемента с np.argpartition

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть массив расстояний между точками `dists`. Расстояния в нем записаны в произвольном порядке. Я хочу найти индекс минимального расстояния. Для этого использую `np.argpartition` следующим образом:

```
indices = np.argpartition(dists, number)[:number]
```

Если я задаю `number = 1`, то получаю

> [413]

Если `number = 5`, то

> [375 410 413  58  51]

Если `number = 10`, то вывод

> [  58   29  413  166  410   92 1980  375   51 2043]

Правильный ответ в задаче — 413 (то есть получаю только при `number = 1`). Я думал, что `np.argpartition(dists, n)[:n]` вернет мне индексы `n` минимальных элементов массива по возрастанию для любых `n`, то есть индекс 413 всегда должен был бы быть первым в списке в моем случае. Подскажите, какова логика `np.argpartition(dists, n)[:n]` для `n > 1`?

Comment: Попробуйте так: np.argpartition(dists, range(n))[:n]

Comment: @MaxU Большое спасибо! Да, работает. Не могли бы пояснить почему и что происходит за сценой (в чем интуиция)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[np.argpartition(a, kth,  axis=-1, kind='introselect', order=None)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) возвращает индексы (позиции) элементов массива `a` таким образом, чтобы `kth` элемент(ы) массива соответствовал(и) позициям в отсортированном массиве `a`.

**NOTE:** порядок всех остальных элементов не гарантируется (может, но не должен, совпадать с отсортированным массивом).

Пример:

```
In [8]: a = np.array([30, 40, 20, 10])
```

получим индексы массива таким образом, чтобы 3-й (последний) элемент оказался в отсортированном массиве (позиции остальных элементов не определены):

```
In [9]: np.argpartition(a, 3)
Out[9]: array([2, 3, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
#                       ^
```

тоже самое, но теперь покажем элементы вместо индексов:

```
In [10]: a[np.argpartition(a, 3)]
Out[10]: array([20, 10, 30, 40])
#                           ^^
```

теперь получим индексы первых двух элементов в отсортированном массиве:

```
In [11]: np.argpartition(a, [0, 1])
Out[11]: array([3, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
#               ^  ^

In [12]: a[np.argpartition(a, [0, 1])]
Out[12]: array([10, 20, 40, 30])
#               ^^  ^^
```

---

PS если нам надо отсортировать небольшую часть большого массива, то `np.partition()`, `np.argpartition()` будут работать гораздо быстрее по сравнению с `np.sort()`, `np.argsort()`, которые сортирует весь массив целиком:

```
In [15]: a = np.random.rand(10**7)

In [16]: %timeit np.partition(a, range(10))[:10]
358 ms ± 5.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [17]: %timeit np.sort(a)[:10]
2.58 s ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Если вас интересует только минимальный элемент, то выгоднее будет воспользоваться функцией [ndarray.min()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) / [ndarray.argmin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html):

```
In [19]: %timeit a.min()
10.2 ms ± 18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit np.partition(a, 0)
103 ms ± 9.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь понял, в чем дело было.